# Have CXXI support for MSVC ABI now?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++, mono

A year (or 2) passed. Have CXXI support for MSVC ABI now? I we seen [this](https://github.com/mono/cxxi/pull/2) yet have seen no articles on use of CXXI with MSVC ABI compiled C++ DLL's. Have any one tried/tested that it works for real with MSVC ABI?

It seems like there are about 3 of CXXI now:

- [one](https://github.com/tritao/cxxi) with Clang instead of GCC-XML with [sweet automated generation API](https://github.com/tritao/cxxi/blob/master/examples/OpenCV/OpenCV.cs) (seems to be alive, [that probably](https://github.com/mono/cxxi/pull/2#issuecomment-5696679) has MSVC ABI support)
- [one](https://github.com/kthompson/cxxi) that [probably](https://github.com/mono/cxxi/pull/2) has MSVC ABI support and has [MonoDroid usage example](http://rogue-modron.blogspot.ru/2012/05/cxxi-monodroid.html) `problems still present in the master have been solved in the fork, in particular with parameters passed by reference` (seems to be left for a year)
- [original one](https://github.com/mono/cxxi) (seems to be left for a year, MSVC ABI suppor unknown)

Comment: Request for CXXI question tag

Comment: You should discuss with @tritao https://github.com/tritao, as he seams to be the best resource you can consult at this moment.